# vsc++ ,Can I using MFC in a console project and show window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I create a win32 console project with option add MFC, and MSVS produce some code automate for me,if I wanted drawing some windows, do I need derive my own class from CWinApp? or  use an instance of CWinApp directly? 
If I use an instance of CWinApp directly,how do I custom InitInstance function to get the frame that I like?
Simply put,If I want make some windows using the code below,how to do that?

```
int main()
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);

    if (hModule != nullptr)
    {
        // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, nullptr, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
            wprintf(L"Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n");
            nRetCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {

            // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand what you are proposing, while certainly 100% possible, is odd?  And therefore likely difficult?  Cross-process communication between a console-app and an MFC app would be more normal. MFC is supported in console apps mostly for helper classes like CString.

Comment: While it is just an option in the executable header, the extra nasty little detail in C++ is that the entrypoint changes.  So you can't get it linked unless you provide a main() substitute for MFC's WinMain().  Running Editbin.exe with the /subsystem option afterwards ought to be easiest.

Comment: @zzxyz,Hans thank you!!